# While loop in sql for top 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Now, I am trying to get the top 10 data from the table through a loop.

```
 Select ClientUserName, DestHost, count(DestHost) counts  from  #ProxyLog_record  
 where ClientUserName =(Select top 1 ClientUserName from #ProxyLog_count_2) 
 Group by ClientUserName, DestHost order by counts desc
```

What this does only gets the top data from clientusername how can i loop it to where it will get the first, second third,.... tenth data?

Comment: **SQL** is just the **Structured Query Language** - a language used by many database systems, but not a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system (and which version) you're using....

Comment: You don't loop in sql if you can help it. Don't even think in terms of looping through records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't loop but you could do something like this and change the number of records to select in the sub query:

```
   Select ClientUserName, DestHost, count(DestHost) counts  from  #ProxyLog_record  
     where ClientUserName  in (Select top 10 ClientUserName from #ProxyLog_count_2) 
     Group by ClientUserName, DestHost order by counts desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Group by ClientUserName, DestHost order by counts desc LIMIT 10
```

Comment: might work for MySQL - but not for other systems ... OP hasn't indicated what RDBMS he's using ...